# innerhtml not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to insert values into a table using Javascript. It adds row and the required cells, and also an element i want to add, but the cell into which I want to insert a value through `.innerHTML` remains empty.

Here is my code.

```
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "checkbox";
        element1.name="chkbox[]";
        cell1.appendChild(element1);

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1;

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        element2.type = "text";
        element2.name = "txtbox[]";
        cell3.appendChild(element2);
```

`cell2` remains empty...what's wrong with it?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/RpSQ3/)

Comment: What do you expect "cell2" to contain?

Comment: Which browser is not showing contents of cell2?

Comment: I expect 'cell2' to contain text or an integer value, and I've tried it in firefox and google chrome.

Comment: It comes up with a `1` in it for me.

Comment: yea here it is 1, but I have some other cells too, into which I am trying to insert some text data.

Comment: Strange!! see in firebug, break at the line when u insert the text into cell2.
Another possibility, you might be using the same variable after that and accidentally emptying it.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing. It works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/jmorgan123/vB8PN/

I tested it in Chrome and FF on Windows 7 and both worked.

- Are you sure you're setting `tableID` beforehand?
- If `cell1` and `cell3` are getting set, is there a preexisting row in your table with fewer than 3 columns? That could cause odd behavior.
- The only other possibility I can think of - and it's unlikely - is that maybe `cell2` is already defined somewhere. That **shouldn't** make a difference (the variable should just get reassigned) but I don't know what browser you're using, so maybe there's a bug in it. It could be choking on that, even though it shouldn't.

Comment: yea I am sure i am setting it. i am uisng tbl_records as the id.

Comment: @Amjadkhan what browser (and -version) are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This is a weird issue indeed. As most of the answers already stated; it's working just fine in the well known modern browsers.

Since you already said that you're using Firefox and Chrome, it should be working fine in your browsers as well (did you update to the latest and greatest versions, or are you maybe using a beta version?

The only thing I could find is the reference on Quirksmode.org:
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html

It states that `innerHTML` is 'almost' supported in IE5-9. But this is the most interesting part I found there:

> In IE and Konqueror `innerHTML` does not work correctly when you update tables. Solve this by using pure DOM methods instead. See [this explanation](http://www.ericvasilik.com/2006/07/code-karma.html) of the behaviour by `innerHTML`’s inventor.

That could be related to your issue as well, since you're trying to manipulate a table with `innerHTML`. Maybe you should check out that explanation they linked to and see if it works for your situation.